# Rails nested_attributes doesn't work on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have three models

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :provider_contracts, :class_name => "Contract", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :provider_users, :class_name => "User", :through => :provider_contracts

    has_many :customer_contracts, :class_name => "Contract", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :customer_users, :class_name => "User", :through => :customer_contracts

    has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Contract:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :provider_user, :class_name => "Node", :inverse_of => :customer_contracts
    belongs_to :customer_user, :class_name => "Node", :inverse_of => :provider_contracts
end
```

Profile:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I create a User names A, and I want to add a customer to A:

```
user_a = User.create(:name => "A", :profile_attributes => {:company_name => "A Company"})
# success with profile
user_b = user_a.customer_users.new(:name => "B", :profile_attributes => {:company_name => "B Company"})
user_b.save
# success with contract but profile
```

And the result is:

User A is created and with correct Profile

User B is created

User A and User B have correct Contract

But B's profile is created without user_id so the association is not created.

Comment: i have one doubt, why you used user_a for user_b

user_b = user_a.customer_users.new(:name => "B", :profile_attributes => {:company_name => "B Company"})
user_b.save

Comment: It because this situation is about User A want to add a customer to self, and User A is some User’s customer too. I know there is some other way to do this, but my question is nested_attributes not working on this situation? Thanks